# Questions on polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

I was trying to understand Polymorphism in Java but I could not understand certain things in `App.java`.

Q1) Why are we able to do `p2=tree;` even though `p2` is reference to class `Plant` and `tree` is an object of class `Tree`?

Q2) Why does it say `Type Mismatch:cannot convert from Plant to Tree` when I try to do this :

```
tree=new Plant();
```

Q3) Why does `p2.shed()` cause an error even though the output of `b2 is true`? If `p2` is instance of `tree` it should be able to access `Tree` methods.

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Plant p1 = new Plant();;
        Plant p2 = p1;

        Tree tree = new Tree();

        boolean b1= tree instanceof Plant;

        p2=tree;    

        boolean b2= p2 instanceof Tree;

        System.out.println(b1+" "+b2);

        p2.grow();

        tree.shed();

       //p2.shed(); ---- Why is this an error?

   }

}
```

**Plant.java**

```
public class Plant {
    public void grow(){
        System.out.println("Plant growing");
    }
}
```

**Tree.java**

```
 public class Tree extends Plant {

    @Override
    public void grow() {
        System.out.println("Tree growing");
    }
    public void shed(){
        System.out.println("Tree shedding");
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the request for external sources from your question: recommendations are off topic on Stack Overflow and will get your question closed.

Comment: You are human, you also have a gender and can be categorised as a mammal, but you also have a a name and are unique (there's no one else like you in the world), polymorphism is the same concept.  A Object which inherits from a common ancestor (/mammal/human) can behavior as those ancestors.

Comment: this is a homework question.....

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1) Plant is the Parent Class of Tree.
I hope you know That when we do `Plant p = new Plant();` p is the **reference**.
And `new Plant()` is the actual Object.

So,**a Parent Reference can point to a child object.**  So you can do `p2=tree` or

```
Plant p2 = new Tree()
```

2) Now remember the point I wrote above. A Parent Reference can point to a child object. **BUT** **A Child Reference CANNOT point to a Parent Object**
i.e you can't do `Tree t = new Plant();`

3) You cannot do `p2.shed()` even thought p2 actually points to a Tree object  and not Plant object. Because of the Reference restriction.

See the Reference variable "**p2**" is of Type **Plant** and is **pointing to** an object of **Tree** Type. **But the reference p2 doesn't know that it is pointing to an object of Tree type. It thinks that it is pointing to an object of Plant type only.**

So when you do `p2.grow(`) It thinks that it is calling the grow() method of Plant class because p2 is a reference of type Plant.

But when when CPU(The executor of your code) goes to the object that p2 is pointing to, **CPU finds out that this is actually a Tree object and calls grow() method of Tree and not Plant class and hence it print "Tree is Growing " and not "Plant is growing".**

When you do `p2.shed()` you get Compiler Error. **Because in Plant class there is no such method called shed()**. Even though the actual object that p2 points to may have a Tree object with shed() method present. The compiling does not happen.

**Because the reference (p2) doesn't know about the new method shed() that is present in child object.**

**Read ::** Herbert Schildt - Java A complete reference. The language is very simple.

After you gain some experience in Java read Kathy Sierra SCJP 6 to understand Java in depth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you wrote these examples yourself and you understand how using the `extends` declaration in your classes works. It also looks like you are attempting to extend the class Plant, but it isn't declared as an abstract class. Anyway:

To one of your points, the reason that `tree=new Plant();` is throwing an error is because with polymorphism, you have to work from broad to specific.

A Tree is a type of Plant, but a Plant is not a type of Tree, so saying `plant = new Tree();` would be valid, which answers your first question.

Lastly, `b2` is *not* true since p2 is a Plant, because as we said before that a Plant is not a type of Tree.

The reason it is giving you an error, however, is that since p2 is of the class Plant (*not* Tree), it only has one method available, which is `grow()`, and you are trying to call the `shed()` method, only available to Trees.

Comment: On running App.java "b2" comes out to be true

Comment: Plant does not have to be an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Q1)Why are we able to do p2=tree; even though p2 is reference to class Plant and tree is an object of class Tree?

this is valid

> The p1, referencing to a Parent Object, cannot be cast to Child
>   because a Parent is not a Child. But a Child is a Parent since the
>   Child inherits all the methods in Parent class. However, if p1 is
>   referencing to a Child object or a subclass of Child, then you can
>   cast p1 to Child.

```
Parent p1=new Parent();
Child c1=new Child();
p1=c1;
```

Q2) Why does it say Type Mismatch:cannot convert from Plant to Tree when I try to do this : tree=new Plant();

```
Parent p1=new Parent();
Child c1=new Child();
c1=(Child)p1;
```

> You cannot cast a `Child` object to its `Parent` Though it will
>   compile ,on runtime java identifies that p1 holds a reference which is
>   not assignment compatiable with c1 and will throw
>   `java.lang.ClassCastException`

Q3)Why p2.shed() an error even though the output of b2 is true? If p2 is instance of tree it should be able to access Tree methods.

> Reference variable "p2" is of Type Plant and is pointing to an Object
>   of Tree Type. So it will be able to access the method of Plant class

Answer (score 0):

p2 is defined as Plant and It only can call those methods defined in Plant class, but with the logic of instance Tree. How the method shed is not defined in the Plant class, the variable p2 (of Plant class) not know the method shed, by this it can not call at method shed.

Regards.